# How can I generate matrix combination based on provided matrices of 0 and 1 in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a 3x3 matrix of zeros and a 2x2 matrix of ones:

```
a = np.zeros((3, 3), dtype=int)
b = np.ones((2, 2), dtype=int)
```

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1]])
```

I want generate all possible matrix combination from `a` and `b` as follows:

```
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])

array([[0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0]])

array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0]])

array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1]])
```

Is there any method do this quickly? I tried using a `for` loop to modify the values of matrix `a`, but it is rather cumbersome. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am guessing you want to generalize this to a = mxm and b = nxn where m>n. Is it?

Comment: @MohammedAadil Yes. I only provide the a and b matrices above to make it more intuitive.

Comment: Will they always be square matrices?

Comment: @MohammedAadil No. a and b can also be in rectangular shape.FYI, I am actually trying to understand the inventory sorting mechanics in RPG. The a matrix should be the inventory and the b matrix is the item.

Comment: Thats an easy fix. I have added the new answer below.

Comment: I've posted a version that does not use loops and works for any number of dimensions. I wouldn't say it's less cumbersome though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following :

```
m1, m2 = 4, 4
n1, n2 = 2, 3

a=np.zeros((m1,m2),dtype=int)
b=np.ones((n1,n2),dtype=int)

d1 = m1 - n1 + 1
d2 = m2 - n2 + 1

for i in range(d1):
    for j in range(d2):
        temp = a.copy()
        temp[i:i+n1,j:j+n2] = b
        print(temp)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
[[1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
[[0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
[[0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0]]
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 0]]
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1]]
```

Works for all shaped matrices.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: There are better ways to do this, even with loops

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have an `(A, B)` array of zeros (`a`) and `(M, N)` array of ones (`b`). Split the problem by axis. There are `A - M + 1` positions that the ones can occupy in the first axis, `B - N + 1` in the second, and so on for any additional axes. The total number of possibilities is therefore `(A - M + 1) * (B - N + 1)`.

The most intuitive way to visualize the different positions is to think about placing `b` into `a` with some offset. But there is another way. We can look at any given position as a view into an array of ones placed in an array of zeros padded on all sides:

```
m = np.pad(b, np.subtract(a.shape, b.shape))
```

Now you can create a view into `m` for each of the locations you are interested in. For example, if we use `A = B = 3` and `M = N = 2`, the first location would be `m[1:4, 1:4]`, the second would be `m[1:4, 0:3]`, etc. `m` would look like this:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

If you create `m` as a C-contiguous array, you can use the arcane magic of [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) to get all the possible views at once. Starting with `m[A - M, B - N]`, you can add two extra dimension that simply step back one element, using the same strides as `m` in the first two dimensions. This generalizes easily to more than two dimensions:

```
def get_positions(a_shape, b_shape):
    # Check input shapes
    if len(a_shape) != len(b_shape):
        raise ValueError('a and b must have the same number of dimensions')
    d = np.subtract(a_shape, b_shape)
    if (d < 0).any():
        raise ValueError('a must be larger than b')

    # Make padded buffer
    m = np.pad(np.ones(b_shape, np.uint8), d)
    # Find initial offset as a tuple of slices
    offset = tuple(slice(off, None) for off in d)
    # Find new dimensions
    shape = tuple(d + 1) + a_shape
    # Find new strides
    strides = tuple(-s for s in m.strides) + m.strides
    # Make a view
    view = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(m[offset], shape=shape, strides=strides)
    # Return a copy with the leading dims merged
    return view.reshape(-1, *a_shape)
```

The final `reshape` operation is forced to copy the array because it is otherwise a wildly non-contiguous view into the buffer of `m`. If you are OK with that, just return the view with twice as many dimensions.

Your original example becomes:

```
>>> get_positions((3, 3), (2, 2))
array([[[1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1]]], dtype=uint8)
```

This vectorized solution will work for an arbitrary number of dimensions. You can also do a simplified `for` loop in 2D that does not not make copies of the data:

```
a = np.zeros((A, B), dtype=np.uint8)
b = np.ones((M, N), dtype=np.uint8)
m = np.pad(b, (A - M, B - N))

for i in range(A - M, -1, -1):
    for j in range(B - N, -1, -1):
        print(m[i:i + A, j:j + B])
```

You can easily generalize to arbitrary dimensions using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

a_shape = (...)
b_shape = (...)
d = np.subtract(a_shape, b_shape)
m = np.pad(np.ones(b_shape, dtype=np.uint8), d)

for offset in product(*[range(off, -1, -1) for off in d]):
    index = tuple(slice(off, off + sz) for off, sz in zip(offset, a_shape))
    print(m[index])
```

The advantages to using a loop over the `get_positions` function are likely threefold:

1. I expect the loop to be faster
2. The loop uses less memory since it provides real views instead of copying the entire array out.
3. The loop allows you to work with the full 32 dimensions that numpy supports, while the function uses up half of that number for auxiliary axes.